# In Isobaric process, is external pressure equal to gas pressure?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

In which processes are external pressure and gas pressure the same or constant?

Comment: Note that questions looking like homework/test/exam/lab tasks, posted without significant attempts to understand/resolve them, are explicitly off-topic on this site and will be closed. 
// Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the external pressure?